# Function called multiple times react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, functional-programming, mobile-application

This is basically a doubt. I am new to React-Native. 
I have a code something like this:

```
function MainFunction(){
    console.log("A")
    ....code...
  async function apiFunction(){
    console.log("B")
    ....code...
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    apiFunction()
  },[])
  return(

     ...JSX code...
  )
}
export default MainFunction;
```

Now I see that the B is printed only once, which is well and good. But I see that A gets printed multiple times. Is it normal or I messed up with the code? 
If normal, why so? If messed up, well I will try to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: If your app is wrapped in React.StrictMode you will see extra renders that normally won't happen.

Comment: It's how react works, though every render doesn't necessarily lead to a update on the native-view, this depends on whether the returned tree is changed or not.

Comment: Great! Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It's normal because every time this component is re-rendered execute all this code, so you will have n console.log('A') where n is re-render times.

Comment: Thank you, that's all I wanted to hear

Comment: Hey, when I put my app in background and open again. each time I made this flow
More console.logs him execute

How can I Solve it?